# Disable lint on single line within django template in vs code

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, wagtail

Given this html

```html
<div class="img-background" style="background-image: url({% static '/img/information_juniors.jpg' %});">
   <div class="content">
      <h5>Juniors</h5>
      <p>{{ page.juniors }}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to disable linting on the single line containing the django tag in VS Code?

It is bringing up these errors

**) expected**  css-rparentexpected
**semi-colon expected**    css-semicolonexpected
**at-rule or selector expected** css-ruleorselectorexpected
**at-rule or selector expected** css-ruleorselectorexpected

I have this for my args, but I can't find any info on linting and django templates

```py
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
  "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
  "--disable=C0111", // missing docstring
]
```

Comment: why do you pylint and HTML file? `pylint_django` lets `pylint`/`astroid` know of runtime generated methods or properties

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, that was my mistake. For some reason vs code started underlining my template files recently and displaying those problems so I initially assumed it was the `pylint_django` plugin that stopped it previously and could be turned off within the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I thought the `pylint_django` plugin would affect template linting, I installed [django-html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django)
and the flagged problems went away